# Naming - Should I avoid giving Objects the same name as their Classes?

Tags: class, object, naming-conventions

Is it common practice to instantiate a class called, for example, `PDFWriter` as an object also named `PDFWriter`, or should that be avoided? Are there any situations where it would be a problem, and if so, is there a standard naming convention to distinguish between classes and objects?

Edit: How about in VB.net, where the IDE does not allow differentiation by case?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a problem as long as you are using a case-sensitive language where type names and variable names use different case practices.

For example, it should be fine to have a variable called `pdfWriter` or `pdf_writer` of the type `PDFWriter`.

Comment: What about in VB.net, where the IDE doesn't allow differentiation by case? Is different naming between classes and objects justified in VB?

Comment: Sorry, just realised VB does indeed allow you to distinguish classes from variables by case. Eg. `Dim pdfWriter As PDFWriter` is completely valid in VB. Which is a nice touch, as that's common practice in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the beginning of Apple Mac programming, it was all the rage to name things like:

```
PDFWriter aPdfWriter;
```

or

```
PDFWriter thePdfWriter;
```

which is better for languages that prefer the capital on the variable:

```
PDFWriter ThePdfWriter;
```

Nowdays, thats not so much the fashion.

Sometimes you don't care because the type of writer is irrelevant so you just use:

```
PDFWriter writer;
```

or

```
PDFWriter Writer;
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me of the good ol days, when using a computer felt like nothing else on earth. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is as such no standard for the naming convention of objects and classes but it is considered a good practice to take the name of the objects which:-

1) indicate the intent of its use.

2) uniformly structured.

From [here](http://atomicobject.com/pages/Naming+Conventions):-

> Names are vitally important, for the same reason they are important in
>   non-OO languages, but also because of the anthropomorphic nature of OO
>   programming.
>
> It is common in OO languages to name things with the name of the class
>   and a definite or indefinite article (Control, aController; View,
>   theView). These names are fine when something more appropriate can’t
>   be found (List, employees).